# Accessing lastNode value in XML using JavaScript is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome

I am a novice to JavaScript programming with XML. I tried the following example from the book "Inside XML", but couldn't able to get it running.

Following is the HTML code with JavaScript:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
         <TITLE>
             Reading XML element values
         </TITLE>

         <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
              function readXMLDocument()
              {
                  var xmldoc, meetingsNode, meetingNode, peopleNode
                  var first_nameNode, last_nameNode, outputText


                  <!--xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")-->
                  <!--xmldoc.load("meetings.xml")-->
                  parser=new DOMParser();
                  xmldoc=parser.parseFromString("meetings.xml","text/xml");

                  meetingsNode = xmldoc.documentElement
                  meetingNode = meetingsNode.firstChild
                  peopleNode = meetingNode.lastChild
                  personNode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PEOPLE").lastChild
                  first_nameNode = personNode.firstChild
                  last_nameNode = first_nameNode.nextSibling

                  outputText = "Third name: " +
                        first_nameNode.lastChild.nodeValue + ' '
                      + last_nameNode.lastChild.nodeValue
                  messageDIV.innerHTML=outputText
             }
         </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <CENTER>
            <H1>
                Reading XML element values
            </H1>

            <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Get the name of the third person"
                ONCLICK="readXMLDocument()">
            <P>
            <DIV ID="messageDIV"></DIV>
        </CENTER>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Following is the XML code used:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MEETINGS>
   <MEETING TYPE="informal">
       <MEETING_TITLE>XML In The Real World</MEETING_TITLE>
       <MEETING_NUMBER>2079</MEETING_NUMBER>
       <SUBJECT>XML</SUBJECT>
       <DATE>6/1/2002</DATE>
       <PEOPLE>
           <PERSON ATTENDANCE="present">
               <FIRST_NAME>Edward</FIRST_NAME>
               <LAST_NAME>Samson</LAST_NAME>
           </PERSON>
           <PERSON ATTENDANCE="absent">
               <FIRST_NAME>Ernestine</FIRST_NAME>
               <LAST_NAME>Johnson</LAST_NAME>
           </PERSON>
           <PERSON ATTENDANCE="present">
               <FIRST_NAME>Betty</FIRST_NAME>
               <LAST_NAME>Richardson</LAST_NAME>
           </PERSON>
       </PEOPLE>
   </MEETING>
</MEETINGS>
```

But, when I run the code in Chrome, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of null
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Firefox with the firebug plugin to debug but you can use Chrome without any plugins. After loading the page you can press F12 to open the devtools. In the console tab you can see the output of your logs, warnings, errors and there is a command line to execute JavaScript.

Sometimes I make a variable global (check in the code for variable a) so I can type `a.` in the command line and see what properties it has.

One of the problems was that a node includes whitespace so the last node is a textNode containing whitespace in many cases. You should also try to end your statements with ;

Here is the code half debugged, hope it helps:

```
<textarea id="txt">your xml content</textarea>

function readXMLDocument(){
      var xmldoc, meetingsNode, meetingNode, peopleNode,
      first_nameNode, last_nameNode, outputText;


      <!--xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")-->
      <!--xmldoc.load("meetings.xml")-->
      parser=new DOMParser();
      xmldoc=parser.parseFromString(
        document.getElementById("txt").value,"text/xml");

      meetingsNode = xmldoc.documentElement;
      meetingNode = meetingsNode.firstChild;
      console.log("meetingNode is:",meetingNode);
      peopleNode = meetingNode.lastChild;
      console.log("peoplenode is:",peopleNode);
      //use console.log to figure out what the variable could be
      console.log(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PEOPLE"));
      //set a global variable named a to the what you want to inspect
      //in the commandline you can type a. and after the dot the devtools
      //will produce a list of attributes.
      a = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PEOPLE");
      personNode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PEOPLE")
       .item(0).lastElementChild;
      a = personNode;
      //in the commandline I can see a.lastChild is textnode
      //the intellisense gives me an option lastElementChild
      //didn't look it up but it could be Firefox specific
      first_nameNode = personNode.lastElementChild;
      last_nameNode = first_nameNode.nextSibling;
      console.log("there are still some things to fix:",
        meetingsNode, meetingNode, peopleNode,
        first_nameNode, last_nameNode);
      return;

      outputText = "Third name: " +
        first_nameNode.lastChild.nodeValue + ' '
        + last_nameNode.lastChild.nodeValue;
    }
    readXMLDocument();
```